# How can one get a NoClassDefFound for a JDK class/jar?

Tags: java, maven, java-8, dependency-management, noclassdeffounderror

In updating a version of a dependency, I began getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/SSLSession`. javax.net.ssl.SSLSession is a JDK class found in rt.jar. How can updating a dependency cause a JDK jar to not be found?

EDIT: the answer for me is that such a dep change *can't* cause this result. There was a base image change that was not known at the time of asking that was responsible.

I am leaving the question up as I think the replies and comments could be helpful to someone coming here for a similar issue. To such people I recommend: double check you classpath and double check your jdk directory.

Comment: In the changes in the dependency no relevant exclusions are added and the only transitive dependency change in my app is in the version of snappy-java.

Comment: That error means that the class was found,  but something went wrong when the class was loaded. Typically static initialization code failed.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware you are not looking at a `ClassNotFoundException`.

The [ApiDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) states about `NoClassDefFoundError`:
*Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.
The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.*